# cant add record, Java, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table with data. 
for instance I have table user_books.

id_user | id_book

I am receiving each request all set of books that tied to current user.
(1, 2), (1, 7)
So I delete all record from user_books for current user and reinsert them.

And problem is I keep getting errors from Hibernate, removal successful but I can reinsert them because of this warnings.

```
2013-04-18 15:48:40,787 INFO : org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener - HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing
2013-04-18 15:48:40,788 INFO : org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener - HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing
2013-04-18 15:48:40,788 INFO : org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener - HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing
```

Any idea where to look? Why I cant reinsert books with userBook.add( ... ) in Java Hibernate environment ?

Comment: What do you mean with deleting records? Are you working with the table?

Comment: oh, code is pretty huge and not sure I can pull this piece out, but idea the same. Yes, I am working with a table. I have @Entity

Comment: are you trying to update multiple values in the same method?

Comment: yes, and what is weird that first time I can delete and reinsert but when I click SAVE second time it will delete but not reinsert

Comment: so yes, when user does not have book, and I do insert first time it works, but when user already has something I delete and after that can not reinsert. Odd. And see this error above for each record for current user.

Comment: i found out next: I have "set_row" field, so full table 
user_id | book_id | set_row
if I insert 1, 2, 0 | 1, 2, 1 then delete and then insert 1, 2, 0 | 1, 2, 1 again it works, But if I do insert 1, 2, 1 | 1, 2, 2 (set_row different - starting not from 0) and then delete and again insert it wont insert. Any ideas, really stuck on this one. Why set_row not working when starting not from 0

Answer (score 0):

Probably this arise due not correct your persistent object annotation.
I guess it's connect to annotation of your filed and Cascade Type.

Try something like this:

`@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: No, I do not have  cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST

Answer (score 0):

I think Mapping relationship is not defind properly So you must defind mapping relationship in your POJO.hbm.xml class

Try as below,

```
<many-to-one class="VO.regVO" name="uid" cascade="delete"></many-to-one>
```

here many-to-one relationship is defind  with mapping the regVO POJO class Primarykey **'uid'** is now for this current POJO class is work as Foreignkey and cascade **'delete'** will about deletion of one object from the database causing deletion of other (dependent) objects